# php, check the difference in between multiple dates, how to?

Tags: php, mysql, date

i have this table `test` :

```
date         tid
1315976558   6224576
1315981082   6224576
1315976486   6224576
1315976550   6224576
```

what i want is to check the difference in between the dates: `1315981082 - 1315976558`, `1315976486 - 1315981082`, `1315976550 - 1315976486`, and if the difference is smaller than a day then do something

any ideas on how to accomplish this?

thanks

edit: i know that i want to compare the second with the first and the third with the second, etc, but how do i code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select @previous := null;

select datediff(`date`, @previous) as diff, @previous := `date`
from `test`
where diff < 1
```

Comment: basically it sets up a variable to keep the value of the datefield from the previous record, so you can compare the current record against the previous one. if the different between the two is <1 (e.g. less than 1 day), then it'll return this row.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [date_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)

```
$diff = abs($time2 - $time1);
if ($diff < 60 * 60 * 24){
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: i see, but how would apply it to my query?, how do i know which dates to compare

Comment: i mean, i know that i want to compare the second with the first and the third with the second, etc, but how do i code it?